# php upload_max_filesize not changing

Tags: php, apache

in my `phpinfo();` I see that my `php.ini` file is in `/etc/php5/cgi`, I've changed there `upload_max_filesize` to `upload_max_filesize = 2000M`, but in my `phpinfo();` I see that the value stays 2M, and when I upload a file it tells my that I exceed the maximum upload_max_filesize limit, why is that? I've restarted apache but nothing changed, any clues?

ps: using php as fastcgi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`/etc/php/cgi/php.ini` configures only php running in cgi mode (like in lighttpd). you need to make changes on `/etc/php/apache2/php.ini`

Comment: okay I've checked /etc/php/apache2/php.ini, so there I have upload_max_filesize = 100M, but my upload file is about 20 megabytes, why is that?, can't understand from where is getting that setting my php :)

Comment: You need to increase max_post_size as well

Comment: its post_max_size = 100M

Comment: You can see which configuration file is loaded on your php info page: Loaded configuration file

Comment: yep)..I've added there the post_max_size and uplod_max_filesize and it worked....thank you very much!

Comment: I tried using .htaccess file and changing wp-config.php but this was the only method that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For Fedora 20, you can find your environment php.ini files in

/usr/share/doc/php-common/php.ini-development

/usr/share/doc/php-common/php.ini-production

or just do

```
locate php.ini
```

Go on ahead and apply the above changes there.

You don't need to restart the server. Just do

```
sudo service httpd reload
```